# expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, glut

I get the above error and about 101 others (total 102 errors). I searched around and the only solution I found is to include the windows.h library before gl.h. But I am already doing that. So what is the solution? Can anyone help me? I am using glut and opengl. Below is my include process. If you request more of my code let me know

```
#include <stdio.h>           // Standard C/C++ Input-Output
#include <math.h>            // Math Functions
#include <windows.h>        // Standard Header For MSWindows Applications
#include <GL/gl.h>        
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SOIL.h"
```

and this is the complete error list:

```
Error   1   error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152
Error   2   error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glAccum' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1152
Error   6   error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153
Error   7   error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153
Error   8   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glAlphaFunc' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153
Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153
Error   10  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1153
Error   11  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154
Error   12  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154
Error   13  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glAreTexturesResident'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154
Error   14  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154
Error   15  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1154
Error   16  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1155
Error   17  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1155
Error   18  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glArrayElement'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1155
Error   19  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1155
Error   20  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1155
Error   21  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1156
Error   22  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1156
Error   23  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glBegin' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1156
Error   24  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1156
Error   25  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1156
Error   26  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1157
Error   27  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1157
Error   28  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glBindTexture'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1157
Error   29  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1157
Error   30  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1157
Error   31  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1158
Error   32  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1158
Error   33  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glBitmap'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1158
Error   34  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1158
Error   35  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1158
Error   36  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1159
Error   37  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1159
Error   38  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glBlendFunc' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1159
Error   39  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1159
Error   40  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1159
Error   41  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1160
Error   42  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1160
Error   43  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glCallList'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1160
Error   44  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1160
Error   45  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1160
Error   46  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1161
Error   47  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1161
Error   48  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glCallLists' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1161
Error   49  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1161
Error   50  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1161
Error   51  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1162
Error   52  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1162
Error   53  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClear' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1162
Error   54  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1162
Error   55  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1162
Error   56  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1163
Error   57  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1163
Error   58  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClearAccum'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1163
Error   59  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1163
Error   60  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1163
Error   61  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1164
Error   62  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1164
Error   63  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClearColor'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1164
Error   64  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1164
Error   65  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1164
Error   66  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1165
Error   67  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1165
Error   68  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClearDepth'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1165
Error   69  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1165
Error   70  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1165
Error   71  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1166
Error   72  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1166
Error   73  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClearIndex'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1166
Error   74  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1166
Error   75  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1166
Error   76  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1167
Error   77  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1167
Error   78  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClearStencil'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1167
Error   79  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1167
Error   80  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1167
Error   81  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1168
Error   82  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1168
Error   83  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glClipPlane' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1168
Error   84  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1168
Error   85  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1168
Error   86  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1169
Error   87  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1169
Error   88  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glColor3b'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1169
Error   89  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1169
Error   90  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1169
Error   91  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1170
Error   92  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1170
Error   93  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glColor3bv'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1170
Error   94  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1170
Error   95  error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1170
Error   96  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1171
Error   97  error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in formal parameter list  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1171
Error   98  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'glColor3d'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1171
Error   99  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1171
Error   100 error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1171
Error   101 error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1172
Error   102 error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\gl.h 1172
```

Comment: Make sure you have "WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" turned off.

Comment: what is that? a little help please?

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? If so either turn them off or use explicit precompiled headers, not automatic.

Comment: What do you mean? I simply copied the code from one of my projects to a new one so to do some texting with the code for my an app I'm making. (the whole code, nothing left behind, all files and folders, all includes correctly and all file headers and resource files added correctly

Comment: The application compilation settings also have to be correct, including precompiled header settings, preprocessor defines, etc.

Comment: there all the same. that's why I don't understand....

Comment: Well it can't be the same, can it? There must be some difference, you just haven't found it yet. Have you checked the things I mentioned specifically?

Comment: I think I did. But currently I am doing another project that I must deliver by sunday so I won't be rechecking everything until then

Comment: I checked everything and nothing worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is commonly caused by defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, either in `stdafx.h` or in the compilation settings.

Defining that macro before including `windows.h` automatically excludes infrequently used header files and definitions.

Since you are using OpenGL you are using some of those infrequently used headers, so you need to turn that off.

It may appear in a header such as stdafx.h like so:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

Or it may be in the compilation settings like so:

```
-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

Comment: I found this code
#ifdef WIN32
 #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <wingdi.h>
 #include <GL/gl.h>
in soil.c which (soil.h) is included after windows.h (in main.cpp) what should i alter???

edit: I put the 
 #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
in comments and it still did not compile

Comment: Try changing it to `#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and doing a rebuild-all.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, use this `#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and change this  `WIN32` to `_WIN32`.

Comment: Where would we find `-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` in compilation settings in VS? or where would stdafx.h be included from?

Answer (score 5):

You forget to include `windows.h` right before `gl.h`. From http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/gettingstarted.htm:

> ```
> Error:
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\gl\gl.h(1152) : error C2054: expected '(' to
> follow 'WINGDIAPI' 
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\gl\gl.h(1152) : error C2085: 'APIENTRY' : not in
> formal parameter list
> ```
>
> Didn't #include windows.h or included it after gl.h. Source files that
>   use neither GLUT nor MFC, but which make calls to OpenGL, should:
>
> ```
>      #include <windows.h> 
>      #include <GL/gl.h>
> ```

Works for me.

Also, make sure you are not using precompiled header

Comment: Do you have another c file on your project?

Comment: I think I didn't, so long ago

Comment: "You forget to include windows.h right before gl." What do you mean? The code shown by the OP says `#include <windows.h>` followed immediately by `#include <GL/gl.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

OK I had the same problem and i fixed it  . Just Make sure you dont have other files in your project (precompiled header /.c/ .cpp).Delete them and leave only thouse wich you need  and it will work

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using the SOIL library. Make sure that windows.h is included (the preprocessor might take a different branch). Ensure that WIN32 is defined if you do not want to change the SOIL library. If not, you can replace it by _WIN32.

Answer (score 0):

This all seems to be pretty much wrong guys (sorry!).

Simply because this loudly proclaims that
including windows.h is needed does not mean that
including windows.h should be done.

OpenGL is an OPEN STANDARD PROTOCOL INTERFACE SPEC. Thus,
its related STANDARD headers (GL/gl.h , GL/glu.h etc.) should **DEFINITELY NOT** be causing massive pollution with
whichever proprietary crap some proprietary vendors manage to come up with.

Specifically, I am talking of
woefully Win32-specific macros WINGDIAPI and APIENTRY, which
have been ADDED TO
previously standard GL header content (hint: see SGI text in that header), and which
cause these GL headers to **NOT** be a properly self-contained and generic interface any more!!
(i.e., requiring a whole ton of wingdi.h and kitchen sink etc., with the massive consequence of globally polluting your entire source code scope with this wholly environment-specific crap, windows.h etc)

Thus, to rectify this dire situation, things likely should be done like this:

1. create purpose-specific local headers which try to do a maximally precise job of
   supplying these few required-but-missing (non-self-contained header!) environment-specific parts:

- APIENTRY definition header file
- WINGDIAPI definition header file

2. supply these missing parts (broken since non-self-contained OpenGL interface...) by including these helper headers everywhere that you include related official GL headers (interfaces!) - on the Windows-proprietary platform only (#ifdef _WIN32)!
3. **take uttermost care to** keep any and all Windows-proprietary transition-to-OpenGL helpers (those which make use of Win32 HDC etc., e.g. wgl*() APIs) handling to their own properly strictly isolated translation unit (.cpp)
4. keep all of your standard / generic / cross-platform / universal (read: innocent ;-)) OpenGL implementation handling parts to their own translation units (thus, cleanly **NOT** infected by environment-specific windows.h crap, thus properly working on all platforms)
5. profit! (hopefully)

Topically related reference (potentially already helpful):

[github WindowsHModular](https://github.com/Leandros/WindowsHModular)

Topically related stuff:

- Win32 min / max macro "namespace" / symbol pollution (early-define NOMINMAX and prefer using __min / __max where still needed)
- Win32 near / far macros

The fact remains that it is very intrusive behaviour to be polluting a standard, minimalist(?) interface (OpenGL) with negligible parts (in this case, symbol export macros) of a factually *foreign* toolkit, thereby necessitating sufficiently (header-side!) global-scope pollution of supposedly *generic* user code with wholly environment-specific crap: windows.h (as opposed to simply ensuring that these public interface headers have their own compiler-specific symbol export macros provided within scope already).

tl;dr: "One platform enabled, eleven platforms broken - job achieved"